# What is the definition of the norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $x$ and $y$ be in $ \mathbb{R}^{n}$. I know from the definition of norm that $\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}$. Can anyone tell me what will be the norm of $\|x-y\|$? Is it $\sqrt{\sum_{1}^{n}(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2}}$?

Comment: Yes,thats the definition of the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of not leaving unanswered questions: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is the norm of $||x-y||$ as you mentioned. By the way, when you have a norm for a  space, i.e, $||x||$ is defined, you can obtain a metric function for that space by setting $d(x,y) = ||x-y||$. It's easy to verify that this satisfies all axioms of a metric function. So, in other words, every normed space is a metric space.